# Select multiple lines with cursors at each line start in Dr Racket

Tags: racket, multicursorediting

I want to select multiple lines and put a cursor at the beginning of each line in the code editor Dr Racket. I know that this is possible in VS Code and many others but I don't find a keyboard shortcut to do it in Dr Racket. Is it possible? How?

I tried:

- ctrl + shift + L and then put cursor at beginning of each line.
- option + shift + I.
- I'd love to have a solution for both Windows and MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrRacket does not currently support multiple cursors, to the best of my knowledge.